# Is it possible to delete an originated (e.g. KT1...) contract?

Tags: smart-contracts

Is it possible to delete originated contracts? E.g., does Tezos have an analog of Ethereum's `selfdestruct`?

I'm guessing "no" and that it's a deliberate design decision - this is mostly an academic question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Currently, Michelson does not have any instruction for self-destructing a contract.